# CMake GUI can't specify vcpkg toolchain using %VCPKG_ROOT%

Tags: windows, cmake, environment-variables, cmake-gui

Using the CMake GUI on Windows, if I select "Specify toolchain file for cross-compiling" I can then provide the explicit path to my vcpkg.cmake file, and my project will Configure, Generate, build and run.

If I instead provide the path using the vcpkg environment variable `%VCPKG_ROOT%`:

`%VCPKG_ROOT%/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`

...the CMake Configure step fails with the message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:130 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file:
  %VCPKG_ROOT%/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (project)
```

Is there a way to use the vcpkg environment variable here?

Comment: If you're interested in reading related source code, see `QCMakeFilePathEditor` and `QCMakeFilePathEditor` in [`Source/QtDialog/QCMakeWidgets.cxx`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/QtDialog/QCMakeWidgets.cxx), and `CMakeSetupDialog::setupFirstConfigure` in [`Source/QtDialog/CMakeSetupDialog.cxx`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/master/Source/QtDialog/CMakeSetupDialog.cxx).

Comment: How is it related?

Comment: I believe that's the code for the GUI element where you tried to enter a path with Windows-syntax for environment variable references. I'm assuming that Qt (the UI framework/library that cmake-gui uses doesn't do that be default, at least for the element that CMake used here). You can try to see if CMake bundles special logic to handle Windows-style environment variable references. From a cursory glance, I didn't see any.